# Gatsby pages don't programmatically create from data

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to generate pages for my blog using Gatsby (v2.18.17). I have implemented the code example from [part seven](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/) of the tutorial on the Gatsby website where I use the createPages API. The pages do not generate and there are no warnings or errors.

**gatsby-node.js**

```js
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

**src/templates/post.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
export default () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>Hello blog post</div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

The build **output** where only 11 pages generated (8 of which were manually created - I'm not sure what the other 3 pages are)

There should be over 200 pages generated from my markdown blog posts in `content/posts`

```
> gatsby develop

success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.034s
success load plugins - 0.578s
success onPreInit - 0.002s
success initialize cache - 0.007s
success copy gatsby files - 0.071s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.008s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.009s
success source and transform nodes - 0.233s
success building schema - 0.304s
success createPages - 0.101s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.090s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
success update schema - 0.033s
success extract queries from components - 0.270s
success write out requires - 0.046s
success write out redirect data - 0.002s
success Build manifest and related icons - 0.106s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.112s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 3.825 s
⠀
success run queries - 0.039s - 12/12 303.82/s
```

I am wondering if I have a configuration issue within my website somewhere. The slugs are, however, printed during build time when I write the slugs to the console while iterating through the markdown files.

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cbillowes/curious-programmer-nitrogen).

Comment: When I build your project I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined` for `C:/Users/User/Code/curious-programmer-nitrogen/src/components/image.js:6`. Did you restart `gatsby develop` after changing GraphQL queries or editing any of the gatsby config files? This might be why you see no errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That error's bizarre. I replaced `<Image>` to return a `<div></div>` and again, no errors and pages are not generated. What happens if you also change the `Image` component? Do the pages generate?

Comment: Yes, now it works for me. I replaced `return render(image)` with `return <div></div>;`. Your project created 10 pages for me.

Comment: It needs to create over 100 pages if I count correctly. The blog pages aren't being generated for some reason. I wonder why. I am playing around with different versions of Gatsby to see if I get what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gatsby-plugin-routes` in your `gatsby-config.js` interferes with the createPages function inside your `gatsby-node.js` in some way.

Here the `gatsby-node.js` that worked when I edited your project:

```
exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/post.js");
  return graphql(`
{
  allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "content/posts/"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }
    /* --- Create blog pages --- */
    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      console.log(node.fields.slug);
      createPage({
        path: `/blog${node.fields.slug}`,
        component: blogTemplate,
        context: {
          slug: node.fields.slug,
        },
      });
    });
  });
};
```

You need to remove `gatsby-plugin-routes` from your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
/*    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-routes`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/gatsby-routes.js`,
      },
    },*/
```

I would suggest going without the routes plugin until the other parts of your website are running. Each plugin adds complexity to your project and in this case caused a silent failure.

That's a nice blog. I will take some inspiration for my own portfolio. :)

Comment: Thanks! :D For both the compliment and the help. I'll try it out quickly and let you know.

Comment: Legendary! <3 I can now figure out the routing and the image issue knowing that the blog posts actually gets generated.